# Android: disable fsck_msdos on a particular SD card

Tags: android, linux, fat32, fsck

Using a Samsung Galaxy SIII (AT&T version) running Android 4.0.4 with stock Samsung customizations, I am just trying to mount an SD card (through a card reader connected via an OTG adapter to the USB host port).

Unfortunately, this device seems to "have too high standards" for filesys correctness - it refuses to mount the card, saying `Unable to read FAT: Success`.

Other Android devices do not have this problem, perhaps running less extensive checking.

The SIII is able to mount brand new SD cards, but after even a few days of normal use of a class 10 card, the card is not mountable in the SIII, despite being mountable on other Android devices, as well as Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Just like you can put a `.nomedia` file on a disk to disable the MediaScanner, is there something like `.nofsck` that I can put on the cards to disable or restrict the fscking? Alternatively, is there anything that a non-root app can do to disable or restrict the fscking?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want but... if you set OEM field name to "EXFAT   " you can get ~ Blank SD card :))
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/fsck_msdos/+/refs/heads/kitkat-release